# In the Builder pattern why doesn't the Client get the result from the Director?

Tags: design-patterns, builder

If the Client has to ask the Director to create the object wouldn't it make sense for the Client to also retrieve the result from the Director (instead of the Builder/ConcreteBuilder)?

Comment: What's the code of Director, Client, Builder and ConcreteBuilder?

Comment: I can provide some sample code but I thought the point of the design patterns was the lack of need to have one.